# post values to rest API with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The code is not posting data to my API and I need to post vales from register form

I tried to post the data using this method but seems not to be working can anyone point me to the right direction here, also some different ways I can get data from the form efficiently

```
$(function (){
      console.log("Hellows");
      var $businessname = $('#businessname');
      var $email = $('#email');
      var $address = $('#address');
      var $cellphone = $('#cellphone');
      var $username = $('#username');
      var $password = $('#password');
      var $re_password = $('#re_password');


      $('#submit').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({

        url: 'http://slimapp/api/business/add',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
            data:{
               BusinessName: ''+$('#businessname').html($('input:textbox').val())+'',
              email: ''+$('#email').html($('input:textbox').val())+'',
              Address: ''+$('#address').html($('input:textbox').val())+'',
              cellphone: ''+$('#cellphone').html($('input:textbox').val())+'',
              username: ''+$('#username').html($('input:textbox').val())+'',
              password: ''+$('#password').html($('input:textbox').val())+''
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            }
        })
      })

    });
```

Comment: Hard to answer this as you haven't indicated what the REST API expects for data per the API's requirements or documentation. You also say "seems" not to be working. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Add an `error` handler and check all **three** parameters: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ... }`

Comment: No errors in the console but i think i cant get values from textbox

Answer (score 0):

What is this `$('#businessname').html($('input:textbox').val())`. It's worng syntext to get value of textbox.

Here is correct ajax request.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
            url: 'http://slimapp/api/business/add',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data:{
              BusinessName: $('#businessname').val(),
              email: $('#email').val(),
              Address: $('#address').val(),
              cellphone: $('#cellphone').val(),
              username: $('#username').val(),
              password: $('#password').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Needs to prevent default also